# "Catalogue" versus "catalog"

Tags: word-choice

What is the difference between *catalogue* and *catalog*? I cannot really decide which one to use for a *product catalogue* for a shop.

Comment: Similar to "analog" or "analogue".

Comment: I think I have not seen enough of "analogue" to recall that it even exists! (eventhough we officially use Bristish English in my country)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

They have the same meaning. *Catalogue* is used in British English whereas *catalog* is mostly used in American English. I've also seen cases where *catalogue* was used by some American friends, though.

Comment: In the US the British spellings, along with some older archaic spellings like "shoppe" are often used in store names to make the **shop** look a bit classier.

Comment: @T.E.D. No, *catalogue* is not in the same category as *shoppe*.  Nobody actually uses *shoppe*, not even the English.

Comment: I expect to find the pricier items in a (US) *Catalogue*.

Answer (score 0):

Although both spellings originally referred to the same idea, it's my personal experience--in the U.S., at least--that these two forms have diverged over time to encompass separate domains based on the locus of ideas evoked by the word in question.

**Example 1:** "Dialogue" refers to an undefined, dynamic exchange between two active parties (e.g., dialogue between two characters) whereas "dialog" will typically refer to a one-sided exchange--as with a computer prompt with a deterministic output (e.g., dialog box).

**Example 2:** "Analog" (adj) almost exclusively refers to "non-digital" technology (e.g., analog amplifier), while "analogue" (n) is used almost exclusively to describe things in figurative/metaphorical domains.

**Example 3:** "Catalog" and "catalogue" are a good example of this. Catalog often seems relegated to static, physical objects (e.g., the Sears catalog) while catalogue may refer to a more abstract (non-physical) concept of grouped elements (e.g., the Beatles' catalogue of music).

In all three cases, both spellings are used heavily in American English, to different effect; I cannot speak to British (or other regional) English.

Comment: I down voted as the answer is wrong. All the pairs have the exactly the same meaning. It is a question of British and American spelling. -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English-language_spelling_reform#19th_century - "...in August 1876,[...] the American Philological Society adopted a list of eleven reformed spellings for immediate use. These were are→ar, give→giv, [...] guard→gard, **catalogue→catalog**, (in)definite→(in)definit, wished→wisht." -- Not all caught on, but several did including the -logue -> -log suffix.

Comment: I have been accused of taking a "prescriptive" approach to language for denying "linguistic evolution" (by refusing to accept improvised terminology), but I also would not enforce 145-year-old morphology on what is clearly a persistent (and conceptual) difference in vernacular--AKA evolution. 

I respect your opinion, but it seems short-sighted and lacking in depth; the same phenomenon I describe here can be found in multiple Anglophonically-influenced languages & would differ equally based on their respective conceptual frameworks/etymologies. Thank you for the feedback and info, sincerely.

Comment: I agree with this answer. In my experience, a "catalog" refers to a physical magazine of products or similar, whereas a "catalogue" refers to a list of an author's works. Sure, they might have the same definition, but the way they are used differs.